# Is my program with JFrame, JPanel, JButton okay?

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

This is a very basic GUI program with a `JFrame`, a `JPanel`, and a `JButton`. But when i try to execute in Eclipse, it says:

> Exception in thread "*main*" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at FrameTest.main(FrameTest.java:34)

Other things are right. I have saved it in file `FrameTest.java`Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest
{
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b;
    private JLabel l;

    public FrameTest()
    {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui()
    {
        f = new JFrame("My frame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p = new JPanel();

        b = new JButton("My Button");
        l = new JLabel("My Label");

        p.add(b);
        p.add(l);
        f.add(p);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new FrameTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have a compilation error, it's obviously not "ok". Which line is line 34 ?

Comment: Anyway ... I can't spot anything wrong. are you sure you saved your code before trying to (re-)compile it?

Comment: This line is line 34    public static void main(String args[])

Comment: Yes I've saved it in my project.

Comment: The code is ok. Maybe Eclipse has a problem? restart/rebuild project?

Comment: @Jaadu_Gar: your code compiles and runs without a problem. Whatever is wrong, it's not the code.

Comment: actually the code is from one of the tutorial from Youtube with some minor change. Here is the tut.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvTZ2Huo0T4

Comment: i also think that code is just fine.

Comment: did you put it in a package?

Comment: Well .. the code is valid and runs. It's far from decent code: you have import statements you don't need, and the variable names are completely worthless, but it does work. have you tried re-building your project?

Comment: Ok i just been able to run the code successfully in TextPad Editor. That may be of Eclipse problem

Comment: Not if you use eclipse correctly.